# Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.ignite:ignite-examples:jar:2.0.0

Tags: ignite

I am getting miss-jar file errors with .examples/pom.xml. Below is the error message. Anyone knows how to resolve this? Thanks a lot.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project ignite-examples: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.ignite:ignite-examples:jar:2.0.0: Failure to find org.apache.ignite:ignite-apache-license-gen:jar:2.0.0 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to build project with `-am` option, `-am` builds projects that your project depends on